# Rails routing misconfiguration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I get the following error

```
No route matches [POST] "/events"
```

with this setup:

#### config/routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  #...
  resources :events
  #...
end
```

---

#### (...)admin/events_controller.rb

```
class Admin::EventsController < Admin::AdminController
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])

    if @event.save
      redirect_to [:admin, admin_events_url]
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

---

#### (...)admin/events/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @event]) do |f| %>
```

---

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong!

### Update

I get this error when I try to POST the from data while creating a new event entry

---

### Update 2

The opening form tag inside `events/new`:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/events" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_event" method="post">
```

the result of `rake routes`:

```
 admin_events GET    /admin/events(.:format)             admin/events#index
              POST   /admin/events(.:format)             admin/events#create
```

Navigating to `/admin/events/` using `GET` works just fine.

---

### Update 3

It works fine on Windows 8 x64 bit with Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2 and Mongrel. It *doesn't* work with Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.2 and Phusion Passenger on a linux server (the host).

## Update 4

Oh. It appears Rails isn't very happy if you send it a form with `multipart/form-data` encoding! Removing the file-upload fixed this issue.

Comment: That seems like it should work...What does the html look like in your page for the form?

Comment: Have you checked the source of the page and looked at what's in the form tag's action to make sure it goes where you expect?

Comment: @LeoCorrea I know, right. :(

Comment: Also, you might want to run `rake routes` just as a sanity check to make sure `/admin/events` does actually exist.

Comment: JasonSwett Yeah. I even checked inside Chrome's Developer console to see where it's `POST`ing the data. It is sending the data to `/admin/events`, but the error says `/events` is missing D:

Comment: @JasonSwett I ran `rake routes` a few times. It's there!

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: @LeoCorrea A gazillion times.

Comment: Notice the error says no route for `/events`... his route is namespaced under admin, so he actually wants to hit `/admin/events`

Comment: If you navigate straight to `/admin/events`, does that work?

Comment: @rthbound that's what the form_for `[:admin, @events]` should do. It uses the `:admin` to go to the namespace. Notice he said his HTML proves so.

Comment: @JasonSwett If you mean using `GET /admin/events`, yes that works like magic.

Comment: It's probably on the redirect then. Stick some `puts` in your controller action and see if the request is trying to redirect or render new.

Comment: Did you try sticking some `puts` in that create action to see if you're not getting there?

Comment: @LeoCorrea This is a PhusionPassenger-running app. I can't use `rails server`, because the app is running on a weird host. :(

Comment: use rake routes to see info about the configured routes. There you can take the name of the route from

Comment: @awenkhh he already posted the rake routes...@starship do you have access to the production logs?

Comment: @Leo Correa sorry - my oversight ...

Comment: Where else are you using path/url helpers?  You can generate a `RoutingError` simply by using the helpers incorrectly: e.g. `admin_event_path` should generate a RoutingError

Comment: @rthbound. That could be the case but he says the error happens when he does the post on the form and the form just goes to POST admin/events and he removed any render so I doubt that would generate it.

Comment: can you try to do a `curl -X POST yourdomain.com/admin/events` and post what returns from that?

Comment: So. I added `post "events" => "admin/events#create"` to the routes and it suddenly worked (not as it should)? I am clearly posting to "admin/events", not "events" the form shows it, the HTTP logs show it. I am completely baffled.

Comment: @LeoCorrea it appears the error was caused by the multi-part/formadata encoding set by the file-upload element. How odd.

Comment: Wow, that's very odd...that shouldnt have anything to do with the route matching?

Comment: @LeoCorrea I know, right. I can't reproduce the error on my computer or on another server. I am thinking it might be something related to the host (some sort of misconfiguration perhaps?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth the only thing that looks fishy to me about your controller is your redirect. You should be able to just do:

```
redirect_to admin_events_path
```

Comment: Did you mean `admin_events_url`? Also, I just tried it and I still get the same error.

Comment: I don't think he meant url. Notice your routes say admin_events. If you stick a _path it should work with redirect_to without having to add the [:admin]. Anyway I'm a bit lost if that didn't fix your problem.

Comment: I tried removing the `redirect_to` and `render` methods from the controller completely, and I still got the same error. *sigh*

Comment: I mean path, but url should have the same behavior. It's a named route so you don't need to prefix it the way you do the object in form builder.

Answer (score 1):

Please try setting up your form this way:

```
form_for(@event, { url: admin_events_path, method: "POST" }) do
```

Comment: This may (perhaps) be a working solution, but it doesn't help if he wants to do it the "right way".

Comment: Not sure how this would be the "wrong" way: `form_for(record, options = {}, &proc)`

Comment: This actually gives me an argument error (the form_for method accepts only 2 arguments (+ block), and there is three here.) Unless you meant `form_for(@user, :method => "POST", :action => admin_events_path)`, which gives me a `undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class` error.

Comment: You should change `path:` to `action:`, I believe.

Comment: @starship I think `url:` actually... [source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Comment: @rthbound Oh, you are right. Well, the missing-route error remains with this approach, too. :(